# Custom Taxonomy Tag Cloud?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I found that I can do
`<?php wp_tag_cloud( array( 'taxonomy' => 'name', 'format' => 'list' ) ); ?>`

But I want the list to be seperated by the letter. Alphabeticaly is what I want. So it would display the letter A then all names with that letter and the letter B with all of the b's and so on.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly do you mean by separated?

If you want multiple tags clouds you will probably need to:

- fetch full list of terms;
- split it into groups by your criteria;
- call `wp_tag_cloud()` for each group, using `include` argument to use specific subset of terms.

Comment: Well I want to have a page listing all of the custom taxonomies. Then within each letter I want it to be separated but using multiple tag clouds is probably the best way to go.